# WPF textbox binding disappears after navigating forward and back again

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox

I have a WPF-application with a mainwindow and different pages. On one of the pages (OverzichtPage) I have a textBox bound to a DataController (Data). (which is a dependencyProperty on the codebehind of the page)  (Might be worth mentioning: the DataController is a Singleton, so that patient is supposed to stay the same and can't disapear..)

```
public static DependencyProperty data = DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(DataController), typeof(OverzichtPage));
    public DataController Data
    {
        get { return (DataController)GetValue(data); }
        set { SetValue(data, value); }
    }


<TextBox Name="naamPatientTxtBox" Text="{Binding Path=Data.Patient.naam, Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=OP}" />
```

At first sight, this binding seems to work. When I navigate to another page by clicking a button

```
<Button Content="Meer info/ Wijzigen" Click="MeerInfoWijzigenBtn_Click" />

private void MeerInfoWijzigenBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri pageFunctionUri = new Uri("View/ZorgTrajectPage1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        NavigationService.Navigate(pageFunctionUri);
    }
```

and navigate back, the binding suddenly stops working. I found out after the navigating back, the naamPatientTxtBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).ParentBinding; is empty. Does anyone have a clue why this binding suddenly disapears after the navigating? I really don't understand how this is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried setting the [KeepAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.keepalive.aspx) property of the page to true?
You might be running into history/caching problems. State isn't autmatically kept.

Comment: Thank you very much Erno! That solved the problem indeed! I'm new to WPF and didn't knew there was something like KeepAlive in the WPF-pages.

Comment: This solves the binding problem. But what if I want the cache not to be persistant (i.e. be sure to have a fresh page)? This binding leak problem on textbox is very odd because I suppose RelayCommands still work...

Comment: @Goufalite - That is a different question and should be posted separately. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654421/detect-navigationwindow-go-back-event

Answer (score 0):

I would put a breakpointat the Loaded event of the parent container (current Window or Page), check the DataContext property (does it contain anything?) and try to reset it if needed.

Another idea would be, set the TextBox.DataContext to Data, then the text to Patient.naam, in that way, it will be easier for you to debug it, also it will allow efficient DataContext inheritance.

Comment: The problem is that it's not the DataContext that is changing. It's the binding itself that becomes a nullreference..

Comment: @StefK I have the same problem for UserControl, can you share the solution?

Comment: @StefK VS shows an error when I add KeepAlive tag to a UserControl. It says that there is no KeepAlive on a UserControl.

Comment: @fatihyildizhan Use KeepAlive on a Page object

Comment: @MauricePheyton KeepAlive is not working for me. I still couldn't fix the issue.