# detect navigationwindow go back event

Tags: c#, wpf, navigationwindow

how to determine when navigationwindow back button is pressed and trap that event to something extra. I am thinking of managing the page state.

Answer (score 4):

Add a handler to either `NavigationWindow.Navigating` or `NavigationService.Navigating`. In your handler:

```
void NavigationService_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back) {
        e.Cancel = true;

        // TODO: whatever state management you're going to do
    }
}
```

P.s. You will need to register the navigation service. In my code it didn't work on the page constructor because the navigation service was still null. So I added Loaded="page_Loaded" to the XAML page tag and assigned it there:

```
bool _navigationServiceAssigned = false;
private void page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_navigationServiceAssigned == false)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigating += NavigationService_Navigating;
        _navigationServiceAssigned = true;
    }
}
```

The [`NavigatingCancelEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigatingcanceleventargs) contains all of the information about the navigation request you'll need to manage page state.

Answer (score 1):

The `NavigationService` provides a number of events you can subscribe to, if you want to control the navigation process:

- Navigating, when the frame is about to navigate. Set Cancel to true
  to stop.
- Navigated, when navigation has finished but before it is
  rendered
- NavigationFailed, when something goes wrong
- NavigationProgress, when chunks of a remote navigation call are being
  downloaded.
- NavigationStopped, when the StopLoading method is called
  or a new Navigate request is made during downloading
- LoadCompleted, when the   page has been rendered

Comment: how to detect the back button event?

Comment: The event arguments have a `NavigationMode` property you can use.